# How to write test my service activator which has input channel and output channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-jms, spring-boot-test

```
I am trying to write a small test to test if the message arrived at the input channel is processed to the output channel as written in my listener code? Any comments on how can I start?

Update: I have added XML and test class could you please help me guide on how to write the test for this? Do i need to add the channel Interceptor in the test config class or in the same test class where I add the test method?

 

@Override
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inChannel", outputChannel = "outChannel")
    public Message<String> receiveEvent(Message<String> receivedEvent) {
        return receivedEvent;
    }
```

===========================================================

```
**This is my jms-gateway.xml for the inbound gateway of JMS**



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                     xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd">
        
            <context:component-scan base-package="com.notification.application" />
        
            <jms:inbound-gateway id="inboundGateway"
                                 request-destination="inQueue"
                                 error-channel="errorChannel"
                                 request-channel="inChannel"
                                 connection-factory="queueConnectionFactory"/>
        
        </beans:beans>
```

================================================================================================================================================

***This is my Test class which I want to have test of my service activator to make sure message reach these channels***

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration("classpath:jms-gateway.xml")
    @DirtiesContext
    @SpringBootTest
    public class EventListenerTest {
    
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("inChannel")
        private DirectChannel messageChannel;
    
        @MockBean
        private EventListenerClass eventListener;
    
        @Before
        public void config() {
        //how to do ?
            messageChannel.addInterceptor();
    
        }
    
        @Test
        void messageReceived_Test() {
            Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello").build();
            
            messageChannel.send(message);
    
            Mockito.when(eventListener.receiveEvent(message)).thenReturn(message);
    
            //how to do assertion on interceptor?
            Assertions.assertThat(actualMessage).isNotNull();
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test case, add a `ChannelInterceptor` to each of the channels and you can verify the intercepted messages.

**EDIT**

Something like this:

```java
@Test
void test(@Autowired AbstractMessageChannel inChannel, 
        @Autowired AbstractMessageChannel outChannel) throws InterruptedException {

    AtomicReference<Message<?>> inMessage = new AtomicReference<>();
    inChannel.addInterceptor(new ChannelInterceptor() {

        @Override
        @Nullable
        public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
            inMessage.set(message);
            return message;
        }
    });
    AtomicReference<Message<?>> outMessage = new AtomicReference<>();
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    outChannel.addInterceptor(new ChannelInterceptor() {

        @Override
        @Nullable
        public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
            outMessage.set(message);
            latch.countDown();
            return message;
        }
    });

    // send test message to JMS (or directly to inChannel for a unit test)
    assertThat(latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
    // verify inMessage.get() is as expected
    // verify outMessage.get() is as expected
}
```

This assumes JUnit5; if you are using JUnit4, auto wire the channels as fields in the test instead.

**EDIT2**

Here is the complete app; works fine for me.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So71942436Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So71942436Application.class, args);
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inChannel", outputChannel = "outChannel")
    public Message<?> handle(Message<?> msg) {
        return msg;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outChannel")
    public void dump(Message<?> msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

}
```

```java
@SpringBootTest
class So71942436ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void test(@Autowired AbstractMessageChannel inChannel,
            @Autowired AbstractMessageChannel outChannel) throws InterruptedException {

        AtomicReference<Message<?>> inMessage = new AtomicReference<>();
        inChannel.addInterceptor(new ChannelInterceptor() {

            @Override
            @Nullable
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                inMessage.set(message);
                return message;
            }
        });
        AtomicReference<Message<?>> outMessage = new AtomicReference<>();
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        outChannel.addInterceptor(new ChannelInterceptor() {

            @Override
            @Nullable
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                outMessage.set(message);
                latch.countDown();
                return message;
            }
        });

        inChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
        // send test message to JMS
        assertThat(latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
        // verify inMessage.get() is as expected
        // verify outMessage.get() is as expected
    }

}
```

Test is green.

Comment: Thanks @Gary, II added my jms-gateway.xml that I load to set up, could you please help me understand how to add channel interceptors in test class?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: let me take a look and try

Comment: Based on your last post, @Gary the channel that I am using inside the code is the Direct channel since I use p2p messaging, do you think AbstractMessageChannel will work?

I did this 
atAutowired
    atQualifier("inChannel")
    private AbstractMessageChannel messageInChannel;

    atAutowired
    atQualifier("outChannelChannel")
    private AbstractMessageChannel messageOutChannel;

gives me an error channel either missing qualified bean or NPE. 
top of test with junit5

-ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
-ImportResource("classpath:jms-gateway.xml")

Comment: As you can see, putting code in comments is not easy to read; better to edit the question and comment that you have done so. `DirectChannel` is a subclass of `AbstractMessageChannel`; it works fine for me; are you sure you are including the configuration file with the service activator? Don't you need an `@Import` for that class? Or, are you using component scanning? I have updated the answer with the complete app.

Comment: Really sorry for putting the code in the comments, my bad. Yes, it works now for me as you explained. I am using component scanning in the configuration class I created to have all channels and queues created. For the test, I used SpringBootTest and SpringExtension and it worked for me as the same example you explained in your answer. The only question I have is what is the best practice to add the configuration file in the test too or SpringBooTest takes care of those things along with spring extension.

Comment: You don't need the extension; if you open `@SpringBootTest` you will see that it is meta-annotated with the extension so adding it again is redundant. Similarly, outside of Spring Boot, you can use `@SpringJUnitConfig` which is similarly meta-annotated (as well as `@ContextConfiguration`).

Comment: Thanks, Garry, that solves my problem, Thank you so much for your help. If you can forward me some sample URL where the Spring Integration tests are available to read that would be great. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing   and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/basic/testing-examples and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/advanced/advanced-testing-examples some of them might be a bit out of date.